# checksum of a byte array

Tags: arrays, go, checksum

I have a `[]byte`, made from a string:

```golang
    array := []byte("some string")
```

It looks like expected:

```golang
    [115 111 109 101 32 115 116 114 105 110 103]
```

Is there a way to simply get the checksum of []byte? Like:

```
    sum(array)
```

Comment: If you want to simply sum the individual bytes as integers you do the following: https://play.golang.org/p/kG_BomiGQ9v. There's also [`hash/adler32`](https://pkg.go.dev/hash/adler32@go1.17.1#Checksum), [`hash/crc32`](https://pkg.go.dev/hash/crc32@go1.17.1#Checksum), and [`hash/crc64`](https://pkg.go.dev/hash/crc64@go1.17.1#Checksum).

Comment: What is larger goal here? The example string is a simple ASCII format. Go strings can contain any UTF8 character, so individual runes can span multiple bytes.

Comment: @colm.anseo Im using this as a checksum for FIX message:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_Information_eXchange#Trailer:_Checksum

Comment: @gg Edit the question to state that you want to compute the FIX message sum.  This will save people the trouble of writing answers that don't solve your problem.

Comment: There is no sum(array). Just change int to byte im yout function. They should be truncated to 256 on each operation so that should give you the right response. Anyhow, write tests first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need md5.sum to check reliability.

https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/md5#Sum

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    data := []byte("some string")
    fmt.Printf("%x", md5.Sum(data))
}
```

Another example.

https://play.golang.org/p/7_ctunsqHS3

Answer (score 1):

I think it's good to avoid using `fmt` for conversion when possible:

```
package main

import (
   "crypto/md5"
   "encoding/hex"
)

func checksum(s string) string {
   b := md5.Sum([]byte(s))
   return hex.EncodeToString(b[:])
}

func main() {
   s := checksum("some string")
   println(s == "5ac749fbeec93607fc28d666be85e73a")
}
```

https://godocs.io/crypto/md5#Sum

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
)

func GetMD5HashWithSum(text string) string {
    hash := md5.Sum([]byte(text))
    return hex.EncodeToString(hash[:])
}

func main() {
    hello := GetMD5HashWithSum("some string")
    fmt.Println(hello)
}
```

You can it on [Golang Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/S38nE-jKSjw)